# Submitting an angular form without (ngSubmit) to avoid CORS policy errors

Tags: angular, forms, angular-forms

How can I submit the following form which is inside an angular component? Clicking on the `Send` button does not trigger any action.

```
  <form method="post" action="https://blub.shtml" id="form" name="form" target="_parent">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="data" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
  </form>
```

I can't use `(ngSubmit)` because of the CORS policy of the server.

Comment: Is this during debug only? I mean, is it deployed on the same url in production? With ng serve you can 'spoof' the requests to avoid the CORS policy.

Comment: The server on https://blub.shtml is an external service where I dont have access to.

Comment: Then you cannot access the service from a website. That's what CORS is about. You need to create a proxy on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a way: Not using a `FormGroup` and `ngNoForm` lets you submit the form "non-ajax-way" by clicking on the button:

```
  <form ngNoForm
        method="post"
        action="https://blub.shtml"
        target="_parent"
  >
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="{{data}}">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
  </form>
```